# finishing a tile to tile edge

Tags: tile

The previous owner re-tiled the master bath floor. There are two places that look unfinished. The first is where the floor tile meets the bath tub tile:

[image]

And the second is where the tile meets the cabinets:

[image]

How do we finish these two interfaces?

Comment: The question verges on decorating advice, which is off topic, but typically it's wooden base shoe around the cabinet and the same or a tile cove (or just grout) at the wall.

Comment: That's what I was thinking already. If they hadn't done such a piss poor job of cutting the tiles, I probably would just grout where the floor tile meets the tub surround. But as you can see from the picture, the gap is horribly uneven. I was hoping for a technique or product that I wasn't aware of. I guess I'm just out of luck.

Comment: If the gaps are not very large you could try grouting them and see if they don't show much. Otherwise, shoe molding as others have said.

Answer (score 2):

Caulk.   Something that matches your floor grout is preferred so go with a regular or even sanded colored silicone caulk (I have used [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00X66X2P0)).   I did notice that some of the tile is butted on the other tile and some with a good 1/8-1/4" gap.   I would lay a layer of caulk down on the large gaps flat to tile.   Let it dry two days then put a layer that is beveled throughout so that you have about 1/8" bead on the "top" of each tile piece.

Comment: Good advice. You hardly ever see this done as everyone is in a rush these days and need a 'do-it-once-and-right-now' solution! But it will improve your chances of making a really neat job in my opinion. Smoothing over thick caulk can be tricky, filling in the deep parts first helps in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting. In the UK the rule of thumb is to use a silicone bead at changes of direction or changes of material. Certainly the wall to floor junction, tile-to-tile would be silicone. Tile to wood cabinet would still be a sealant, but you'd choose one suitable for painting in the future.